# Autowiring not working in SpringBoot controller

Tags: spring-boot, controller, autowired

Hi i was trying to work over an existing SpringBoot application. I created a service class and tried to autowire it in the existing controller, but when trying to build, its failing saying bean injection failed.

> Cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'controller': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.disooza.www.card.dispenser.service.FilaPartnerService
>   com.disooza.www.card.dispenser.controller.CardDispenserController.FilaPartnerService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.disooza.www.card.dispenser.service.FilaPartnerService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)

Following is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/service")
public class CardController {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CardController.class);

  @Autowired
  private CardDao dao;

  @Autowired
  private PaymentService paymentService;

  @Autowired
  private FilaPartnerService filaPartnerService;
```

FilaPartnerService is the newly created interface, and rest all autowires are working fine in this controller. 
Interesting thing is when I try to place **this service class in any other controller it is working fine**. Any help over this issue will be appreciated, since I'm stuck with it.
This is my service interface:

```
@Service
public interface FilaPartnerService {
  RetrievePaymentTokenResponse retrieveXXX(SupplierRequest request);
}
```

This is the implementation class:

```
@Component
public class FilaPartnerServiceImpl implements FilaPartnerService {

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private RetrieveRequestBuilder retrieveRequestBuilder;

  @Value("${filaPartner.url}")
  private String filaServiceUrl;

  @Override
  public RetrievePaymentTokenResponse retrieveFilaPaymentToken(SupplierTokenRequest request) {
    RetrievePaymentTokenResponse tokenResponse = null;

    RetrievePaymentTokenRequest paymentServiceRequest = retrievePaymentTokenRequestBuilder.retrievePaymentTokenRequestBuilder(request);
    try {
      tokenResponse =
          restTemplate.postForObject( FilaServiceUrl, paymentServiceRequest, RetrievePaymentTokenResponse.class);
    } catch (RestClientException exp) {
      //TO-DO return error code
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: is that the full stack?

Comment: 1st: remove the @Service from FilaPartnerService  interface. Stereotype interfaces are only working on classes. Show us your Spring Config.

Comment: Did you try using the @RestController annotation instead of @Controller?